# Показать метку на всех устройствах

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

Работаю с Google-картой, используя Xamarin. Мне нужно, чтобы метку (маркер), которую я поставил в своем приложении, увидели все устройства.

К примеру: я создал новую метку на карте и эта же метка отобразилась на другом устройстве.

Пока в голове крутится такая мысль: при создании метки посылать на сторонний сервер координаты метки (который в свою очередь сохраняет ее) и в приложении делать все время запросы и при появлении новой метки ее показывать на карте.

Правильно ли я думаю? Может есть другие более легкие способы? Решил сначала спросить, прежде чем начать реализовывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, синхронизация через сервер - правильное решение. Для такой простой задачи (отображение у клиентов общей простой инфы с сервера) можно даже взять готовое решение типа Firebase. Вот даже какая-то либа под Xamarin есть:

[Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin)

Общая идея такова:

1. Клиент подписывается на получение всех элементов из выборки в БД.
2. При изменении БД у клиента будет вызван метод, в который придёт изменённая инфа
3. При добавлении клиентом инфы в удалённую БД она появится у всех остальных подписанных клиентов.

По факту вам надо лишь составить модель данных, отправить её и получать её же. Все методы для этого в либе есть и кода нужно минимум. А серверного кода не нужно вообще.

---

Стоит учесть, что в РФ в данный момент не очень ясно как будет FireBase работать, ибо гугл делал НЕмассовую расылку юзерам о прекращении работы с физ.лицами из-за нежелания возиться с НДС. Но вот лично у меня пока что всё работает и писем таких не было. В любом случае есть аналогичные сервисы, в т.ч. отечественные

---

Кажется, прямо сегодня Realm запилил аналог FireBase, который можно поднять на своём сервере. В итоге получается та же штука что и с Firebase, только на своём сервере и через привычный Realm.

https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/linux/

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать

Comment: не подкинете хороший пример, где все подробно расписано ? спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze, по мне так вполне нормально всё описано в доках сервиса, да и в самой либе в ридми. Ну или попробуйте любую статью на тему с хабра

Comment: оно же подойдет, если я пишу в VS ?

Comment: @Lolidze, я не знаю. Я не умею в Xamarin.

Comment: а можно ли как-то грузить только отдельную ветку ? просто, если в бд будет большое кол-во записей, то будет затрачено много трафика для загрузки

Comment: Мне непонятно что вы имеете в виду под веткой. По идее вы можете задать какое-то поле для фильтрации данных и в запрос указать, что возвращаемые данные должны в этом поле иметь определённые значения. Так вы получите не все данные разом.